# Apple Metal: How to work with arrays (not textures) in a kernel shader?

Tags: tuples, metal

I cannot get an array of [Int32] into my kernel shader.

Using a bridging header I can get in an array of structs like

```
typedef struct {
   int ar[100];
} MyArray;

kernel void myShader(device MyArray *in [[buffer(0)]],
                     device MyArray *out [[buffer(1)]],
                     uint threadIndex [[thread_position_in_grid]])
```

and then indexing with threadIndex I can change that array and get it back to the CPU, but …

… Swift sees, not an array but: a TUPLE!

Actually, it’s worse than that. To initialise my input I had to provide a tuple too. 100 elements!

Since I want to work with a large array, this is hopeless. I cannot figure how to build a tuple from an array and the thought of initialising a huge tuple is … well, you can imagine.

Instead, I have tried abandoning the bridging header and using a Swift struct and redefining it in the shader as

```
struct MyArray {
   var ar:[Int32]
}
```

and

```
typedef struct {
   int ar[100];
} MyArray;
```

The shader doesn’t complain but the Swift code crashes if I try to change the indices in the array. For instance

```
out[threadIndex] = in[threadIndex];            // copy array
```

works, but

```
int index = 99-threadIndex;
out[index] = in[threadIndex];      // reverse array
crashes.
```

Can anyone explain this or explain how to handle the tuple problem?

Comment: This is not even a Metal problem, this is a Swift problem. Honestly, I would just allocate an `MTLBuffer` and then bind its memory to a type you want with capacity and work with it like that.

Comment: Do you need a struct, or do you just need an array of Integers?